# PWM on raspberry pi frequency always low

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, wiringpi, pi4j

I wrote a program in java using the pi4j library, i tried setting the frequency divisor as low as possible as you can see, but i'm getting an output frequency of about 1Hz and i can't seem to get it any higher. Any thoughts?

```
public class PwmController {

    GpioController gpio;
    Pin pin1;
    Pin pin2;
    Pin pin3;
    Pin pin4;
    GpioPinPwmOutput motor1;
    GpioPinPwmOutput motor2;
    GpioPinPwmOutput motor3;
    GpioPinPwmOutput motor4;

    public PwmController(GpioController gpio, Pin pin1, Pin pin2, Pin pin3, Pin pin4) {
        this.gpio = gpio;
        this.pin1 = pin1;
        this.pin2 = pin2;
        this.pin3 = pin3;
        this.pin4 = pin4;
        motor1 = gpio.provisionPwmOutputPin(pin1);
        motor2 = gpio.provisionPwmOutputPin(pin2);
        motor3 = gpio.provisionPwmOutputPin(pin3);
        motor4 = gpio.provisionPwmOutputPin(pin4);

        com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.pwmSetMode(com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.PWM_MODE_MS);
        com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.pwmSetRange(1000);
        com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio.pwmSetClock(1);
        setPwm(500,300,200,100);
    }

    public void setPwm(int pwm1,int pwm2,int pwm3,int pwm4) {
        motor1.setPwm(pwm1);
        motor2.setPwm(pwm2);
        motor3.setPwm(pwm3);
        motor4.setPwm(pwm4);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to 'wiringpi'? Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: you set the clock to 1 so you get 1hz. If you set it to 50 you'll get 50 Hz.